# How to generate a xml file into a loop method?

Tags: java, xml

I want to create a xml file and I've seen this example (https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/) however, I want to generate it inside  a loop method.

```
<company>
    <staff id="1">
        <firstname>yong</firstname>
        <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
        <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
        <salary>100000</salary>
    </staff>
        <staff id="2">
        <firstname>hif</firstname>
        <lastname>kiuk kim</lastname>
        <nickname>gonuy</nickname>
        <salary>50000</salary>
    </staff>
</company>
```

But, using the code:

```
public void printXml(String firstName, String lastName, String nickname, String salary) {

  try {

    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    // root elements
    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
    Element rootElement = doc.createElement("company");
    doc.appendChild(rootElement);

    // staff elements
    Element staff = doc.createElement("Staff");
    rootElement.appendChild(staff);

    // set attribute to staff element
    Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
    attr.setValue("1");
    staff.setAttributeNode(attr);

    // shorten way
    // staff.setAttribute("id", "1");

    // firstname elements
    Element firstnameElement = doc.createElement("firstname");
    firstnameElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(firstName));
    staff.appendChild(firstnameElement);

    // lastname elements
    Element lastnameElement = doc.createElement("lastname");
    lastnameElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(lastName));
    staff.appendChild(lastnameElement);

    // nickname elements
    Element nicknameElement = doc.createElement("nickname");
    nicknameElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(nickname));
    staff.appendChild(nicknameElement);

    // salary elements
    Element salaryElement = doc.createElement("salary");
    salaryElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(salary));
    staff.appendChild(salaryElement);

    // write the content into xml file
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\file.xml"));

    // Output to console for testing
    // StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

    transformer.transform(source, result);

    System.out.println("File saved!");

  } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
    pce.printStackTrace();
  } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
    tfe.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

}

the information on the loop about the company staff is always being replaced and it save only the last info:

```
for (Staff staff: staffList){
String firstName = staff.getFirstName();
String lastName = staff.getLastName();
String nickname = staff.getNickname ();
double salary = staff.getSalary();

printXml(firstName, lastName, nickname, salary);
```

```
<company>
        <staff id="2">
        <firstname>hif</firstname>
        <lastname>kiuk kim</lastname>
        <nickname>gonuy</nickname>
        <salary>50000</salary>
    </staff>
</company>
```

How can I save all info that I get during the loop? Thank you.

Comment: @agagx, if my answer helped you solve your problem, please mark it as accepted. If not, please let me know and I'll try help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Your'e overwriting the file instead of appending to it.

You should initialize `StreamResult` with a stream that can write to a file as well as append to it.
For example, you can use `FileOutputStream`, and pass `true` for its constructor for appending.

However, you need to `close` the stream, so one option would be changing your code so that `printXml` would become `getXml`, and your code would then look as follows:

```
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\file.xml", true);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(stream);
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
for (Staff staff: staffList){
   DOMSource source = getXml(staff);       // call staff's getters inside getXml
   transformer.transform(source, result);
}
stream.close();
```

(You should also move lines 3-4 above to a method named `getTransformer`).